# Exited Emacs without saving, did it save the file somewhere?

Tags: windows-xp, emacs

I am using Emacs on Windows XP. Had it open to take some notes in a meeting, but forgot to create a file first (the text got created in the usual "scratch" buffer). Then I closed a lot of applications after the meeting, forgetting to save the notes in Emacs :(

I know that when I am modifying an existing file, it creates a backup of the old file in the same directory. But I don't know if the information from the scratch buffer is available somewhere after an exit without saving. Do you know if I can restore my information? I haven't shut down/suspended/hybernated the system since, so all temp files should be still accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Buffers whose names start and end with "*" aren't autosaved and don't prompt for save on exit.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent this from happening in the future, try

[How do I change where my scratch buffer is saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875646/how-do-i-change-where-my-scratch-buffer-is-saved)